# Not equals function is also targeting the strings which are allowed

Tags: python

When trying to create limits in my program even when I put the correct string it will still say that I can not do that (but still allowing me to input a command).

I have tried using an else function but that makes it worse by excluding anything  i say.

## When i say:

```
if Intro != ('Price', 'Toppings', 'Bases'):
    print (" I do not think that is one of the available options")
```

## the output is:

```
Type Bases for bases- Bases
*I do not think that is one of the available options*
what base do you want- small
```

Edit: Thank you people who answered

Comment: Do you mean `if Intro not in ('Price', 'Toppings', 'Base')` ?

Comment: In the if-block you also need to exit the program. Use something like `sys.exit(1)`

Comment: You are creating a Python tuple here. Instead do Intro != ‘Price’ or Intro != ‘Toppings’ and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if Intro not in ('Price', 'Toppings', 'Base'):
    print (" I do not think that is one of the available options")
```